# Why does ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(runnable) take more time to run the thread

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool, forkjoinpool

I am using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(runnable)` as a handy way to spawn a thread in many places across my application. But at a particular invocation of that it is taking more time (more than 10 seconds) to invoke the code in the runnable in a thread. What could be the reason for that? How to avoid that?

**EDIT:** As per @ben 's answer, avoiding long running process in thread pool seems to the solution. Creating new thread manually solved my problem instead of using common ForkJoinPool.

Comment: Are you using the common pool in many places? By default it has only as many threads as you have cores, so it's easy to fill.

Comment: It might happen that your pool is filled with too many tasks at once. Besides that I am not entirely sure why it would be slower than spawning a thread as internally it's just a statically constructed threadpool which should not be slower (and no way 10 seconds slower)

Comment: @ben It happens to me to delay to nearly 10 seconds.

Comment: @kayaman Yes. I thought using common pool will be efficient way because it knows how may cores and will utilize that.

Comment: @anyone  Am I required to create a new pool instead of using common pool, will it be efficient to spawn only one thread? I don't want to do this accross application, that is why used common pool.

Comment: @Loganathan Don't use `@anyone` as it works just like `@noone`, i.e., nobody gets notified. When you need no thread pool features and the task takes one second or more, then just spawn a new thread as there's nothing to gain. Thread pools give your control over the number of running tasks and have much smaller per task overhead (I guess, a thread creation costs a lot of microseconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some quick testing I found the issue. Look at the following example code:

```
List<Runnable> runnables = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    runnables.add(() -> {
        System.out.println("Runnable start");
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {

        }
        System.out.println("Runnable end");
    });
}

for (Runnable run : runnables)
{
    //ForkJoinPool.commonPool().execute(run);
    //new Thread(run).start();
}
```

Comment in one of the two lines.
We create a number of runnables that send a message, sit idle for 10s and send a message again. Quite simple.

When using Threads for each of those all Runnables send `Runnable start` 10s pass, all runnables send `Runnable end`.

When using the commonPool() just a number of them sends `Runnable start` 10s pass, they send `Runnable end` and another bunch of them sends `Runnable start` until they are all finished.

This is simply because the number of cores on your system determines how many threads the threadpool will hold. When all of them are filled new tasks are not executed until one thread is freed up.

So moral of the story: Only use a threadpool when you know the way it works internally and that is what you want it to do.

Comment: No, the moral of the story is don't use the commonPool unless you understand how it works. Create your own executor and put how many threads you want in it.

Comment: Well that's a way better way to put it. I will edit.

Comment: @both_of_you At many places across my application to spawn a single thread to run some code in background will it be efficient way to create it manually instead of using any thread pool? I want any recommendation on that. Thanks!

Comment: @Loganathan if it is a minor "task" then using a threadpool is exactly right. A task taking 10 seconds is nothing I would call minor though anymore.
When you create a thread you are paying overhead for the thread creation and the thread shutdown. If your task takes a bit longer that overhead is not really noticable. For a 10 second task spawning a new thread should be a totally fine thing to do.

Comment: I heard of Java8+ `Collections.parellelStream()` use 'forkjoin common pool' internally. In that case if some time consuming tasks run with the `Stream.forEach()` it will be the same case with its performance being low. In that case 'how to avoid such delay' with the parellel stream is being the question now if I opt for it. I was just using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` inspired by its usage in the parallel stream.